# Spring Config server: Truststore not found Resource location must not be null

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config

I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource location must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull (Assert.java:193)
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getURL (ResourceUtils.java:130)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.SslConnectorCustomizer.configureSslKeyStore (SslConnectorCustomizer.java:133)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.SslConnectorCustomizer.configureSsl (SslConnectorCustomizer.java:92)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.SslConnectorCustomizer.customize (SslConnectorCustomizer.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.customizeSsl (TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.customizeConnector (TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer (TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at com.tsystems.iberia.tdev.wsecsccs.WsecSccsApplication.main (WsecSccsApplication.java:12)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    ....
```

As you can see is telling me that:**Resource location must not be null**

My spring configuration related issue is:

```
server.ssl.trust-store: file:keystore.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password: secret
```

Obviously, keystore.jks exist and contains certificate. This is how I've built the ketstore:

```
$ keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -file ra-sec.pem -alias vault.ra-sec.svc -keystore keystore.jks
```

Any ideas?

Comment: where is keystore file path of it? @user

Comment: I don't quite figure out what do you mean?

Comment: `server.ssl.trust-store: file:keystore.jks`. `keystore.jks` is located at the same place where `mvn spring-boot:run` is performed.

Comment: apart from the duplication, you're lacking an [MCVE]

Comment: common this is not duplicate of that @YvetteColomb

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand when this error occurred. Maybe you just need to specify the keystore.jks file in the configuration file.
Add configuration in your application.yml file. 
For example

```
encrypt:
  keyStore:
    location: file://Users/folder/mykey.jks
    password: password
    alias: mytestkey
    secret: secret
```

Comment: It happens when tries to make a https connection.